# Pandas behaviour on stack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets Suppose I have

```
ID A1 B1  A2  B2
1  3  4   5   6
2  7  8   9   10
```

I want to use pandas stack and wants to achieve something like this

```
ID A B
1  3 4
1  5 6
2  7 8
2  9 10
```

but what I got is

```
ID  A   B
1   3   4
2   7   8
1   5   6
2   9   10
```

this is what i am using

```
df.stack().reset_index().
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this using Stack? `append()` method in pandas does this, but if possible I want to achieve using `pandas` `stack()` Any idea ?

Comment: sort on 'ID' column or index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ['A','B'], 'ID', 'value', sep='', suffix='.+')\
  .reset_index()\
  .sort_values('ID')\
  .drop('value', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ID  A   B
0   1  3   4
2   1  5   6
1   2  7   8
3   2  9  10
```

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Aha, my favorite function ~ :-)

Comment: It works if i have uniform digits after letters, For example `A1, B1, A2, B2` but if i have columns like `A1, B1, A100, B100, A20, B20`. Then it treats as a different and when i type `df.columns` basically it gives all those columns as a output.  Can you please help me, how do i fix this ? :)

Comment: @user3280146 I think suffix needs to be '.+'.  Give that a try and let me know.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thanks that suffix solved the problem but `.sort_values()` is ordering my index in ascending orders. if i remove `.sort_values()`, then i get `Id` in bad orders. For example `Id = 1, 2 2,1`. So how do i keep using `sort_values` and at the same time stopping it corresponding values ( eg. `A`, `B`) going from `ascending` or `descending` orders. I want to keep the order of values as original.

Comment: In the lastest version of pandas 0.23.0 you can sort by both index and values using index names. see 
  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50077922/6361531

Comment: Thank you, sorting by multi index solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new `columns` object by splitting up the existing column names.  This takes for granted that we have single character letters followed by a single digit.

```
d = df.set_index('ID')
d.columns = d.columns.map(tuple)
d.stack().reset_index('ID')

   ID  A   B
1   1  3   4
2   1  5   6
1   2  7   8
2   2  9  10
```

---

One-line

```
df.set_index('ID').rename(columns=tuple).stack().reset_index('ID')
```

---

More generalized

```
d = df.set_index('ID')
s = d.columns.str
d.columns = [
    s.extract('^(\D+)', expand=False),
    s.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False)
]
d.stack().reset_index('ID')
```

Answer (score 2):

A more interested way

```
s.groupby(s.columns.str[0],axis=1).agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).stack().apply(pd.Series).unstack(0).T.reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
Out[90]: 
    A   B
ID       
1   3   4
2   7   8
1   5   6
2   9  10
```